# show textbox when checkbox is checked yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I am trying to display the textbox when the checkbox is checked. But i didnt know how to implement it using Yii2. Here is my code:

_form.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox(['uncheck' => false],array('id'=> 'myCheck','onclick'=>'myFunction()'))->label('Has passed away?'); ?>

<div id="text" style="display: none">

    <?=$form->field($model, 'date_of_decease')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter decease date'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'autoclose'=> true,
                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            ]
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var text = document.getElementById("hiddenDiv");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script
```

the javascript is inside the _form.php.

Comment: Can you try `date_of_decease` instead of `hiddenDiv`?

Comment: What is the actual rendered HTML and not that weird templating language

Comment: i've tried 'date_of_decease' but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your onClick into 'onchange'=>'myFunction()'

```js
function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var text = document.getElementById("hiddenDiv");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="text_name" style="display:none" id="hiddenDiv">

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" onchange="myFunction();" id="myCheck">
```

Comment: erm still didnt work. idk how to implement it in yii2. ive changed to 'onchange' but still not working.